Counting elements of the same order in finite regular group
Let $K < S_n$ be a finite regular group and $t\in \mathbb{N}$. What is the cardinality of a set $\{g\in K \ | \ ord(g) = t\}$?
If $K$ acts regular then $|K| = n$, so $t$ must devide $n$. If $K$ acts regular then every $g\in K$ has no fixed points, so it has a cycle structure like $[t^{\frac{n}{t}}]$. If $K$ is cyclic then answer is obviously $\varphi(t)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's function. But I stucked in case $K$ is not cyclic.

If $K$ is abelian it's a product of cyclic groups. Can you use this?
